# Rshiny Highcharter how can I create a piechart that drills down into another pie chart?

Tags: r, shiny, highcharts, r-highcharter

Examples I've seen are bar charts drilling down into bar charts. But I can't seem to find an example of a pie chart that drills down into another pie chart in RShiny.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the `type` parameter in `hc_drilldown()` as shown by editing the example from the [highcharter reference page](https://jkunst.com/highcharter/reference/hc_drilldown.html).

```
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df <- tibble(
    name = c("Animals", "Fruits"),
    y = c(5, 2),
    drilldown = tolower(name)
)

df
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   name        y drilldown
#>   <chr>   <dbl> <chr>
#> 1 Animals     5 animals
#> 2 Fruits      2 fruits

hc <- highchart() %>%
    hc_title(text = "Basic drilldown") %>%
    hc_xAxis(type = "category") %>%
    hc_legend(enabled = FALSE) %>%
    hc_plotOptions(
        series = list(
            boderWidth = 0,
            dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE)
        )
    ) %>%
    hc_add_series(
        data = df,
        type = "pie",
        hcaes(name = name, y = y),
        name = "Things",
        colorByPoint = TRUE
    )

dfan <- data.frame(
    name = c("Cats", "Dogs", "Cows", "Sheep", "Pigs"),
    value = c(4, 3, 1, 2, 1)
)

dffru <- data.frame(
    name = c("Apple", "Organes"),
    value = c(4, 2)
)


dsan <- list_parse2(dfan)

dsfru <- list_parse2(dffru)

hc <- hc %>%
    hc_drilldown(
        allowPointDrilldown = TRUE,
        series = list(
            list(
                id = "animals",
                type = "pie",
                data = dsan
            ),
            list(
                id = "fruits",
                type = "pie",
                data = dsfru
            )
        )
    )
print(hc)
```